# xpath excluding nodes

Tags: html, xpath, screen-scraping

Im trying to get info out of this page http://registroapps.uniandes.edu.co/scripts/adm_con_horario1_joomla.php?depto=IIND&nombreDepto=Ingenier%EDa%20Industrial

These are the values i need to select 
[image: select values]
Right now i have this xpath

/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[td[not(@class="back1" or @class="back3")]]

I need to exclude the "Dias Horas Salon etc.." row. How can I achieve this? ([b[text()!='Horas']]?

Suggestions on how to improve selection are welcomed.

Comment: Why don't use a union select instead of exclusion. And why not just use CSS selector to do this while the page structure is pretty clear

Comment: Im going to look at the union. Im using Scrapy to extract the info, they dont seem to hace a CSS selector in their API.

Answer (score 0):

I would locate the header rows by their text and target the following siblings:

```
//b[.="CRN"]/../../following-sibling::tr
//b[.="Días"]/../../following-sibling::tr
```